# Callback handler not concating string

Tags: javascript, node.js, irc

I am using this code:

```
if (msg[0] == '!web')
{
    var result = '\x032[\x02status\x02]\x03 Web: ';

    checkPortTCP('127.0.0.1', 80, function() {
        result += JSON.stringify(this).slice(1, -1);
    });

    bot.say(channel, result);
}
```

When I type !web in my channel, the result is:

```
 [status] Web:
```

Without the actual output.

checkPortTCP:

```
function checkPortTCP(host, port, cb)
{
    net.createConnection(port, host).on("connect", function(e) {
        cb.call("online");
    }).on("error", function(e) {
        cb.call("offline");
    });
}
```

I am making a status bot for IRC. Final result should be ... Web: Online/Offline

```
result += JSON.stringify(this).slice(1, -1);
```

should concat the result variable and then say it into my channel. But for some reason, it doesn't concat the string.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please formulate a clear question in your post. It's hard to tell what you need help with.

Comment: Simplifying it to http://jsfiddle.net/simbabque/P4U3M/ tells me the problem is not with your `result +=` line. Instead, it has to be with the `on()` handlers. They seem not to work. I am not familiar with node, so I can't help any more. Try adding a default handler or look at the docs for the `createConnection` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because `checkPortTCP` callback executes not right now, but in some delay, so it happens that in your example `bot.say(channel, result);` executes *before* `result += ...`

Try to paste `bot.say(channel, result);` inside `checkPortTCP` callback. So it will be:

```
var result = '\x032[\x02status\x02]\x03 Web: ';

checkPortTCP('127.0.0.1', 80, function() {
    result += JSON.stringify(this).slice(1, -1);
    bot.say(channel, result);
});
```

**Update**

If you want to check multiple services you may write something like following:

```
checkPortTCP('127.0.0.1', 80, function() {
    result += JSON.stringify(this).slice(1, -1);

    checkPortTCP('127.0.0.1', 81, function() {
        result += JSON.stringify(this).slice(1, -1);

        bot.say(channel, result); 
    });
});
```

There is two services check, but you can have more. You just have to nest one check into another and in the last callback call `bot.say` method

Comment: this is working, but my final goal should be a !status that responds with multiple services status, eg. NP: Online, DP: Offline, Web: Online, Auth: Offline But this is the right answer.